# When tcp connection is closed for http2 of okhttp

Tags: okhttp

According to [RFC7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#page-65)

> 9.1.  Connection Management

> HTTP/2 connections are persistent.  For best performance, it is
> expected that clients will not close connections until it is
> determined that no further communication with a server is necessary
> (for example, when a user navigates away from a particular web page)
> or until the server closes the connection.

My Question is
for the http2 implements of [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp), when the tcp connection is closed? App go to background or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by OkHttp’s [Connection Pool](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html). It’ll be closed after 5 minutes of inactivity by default.